# Is the C `=` operator copying memory when applied between structs?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider this example:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    ...
} ReallyBigItem;

ReallyBigItem* array = (ReallyBigItem*) malloc(sizeof(ReallyBigItem) * 8);

ReallyBigItem* item = (ReallyBigItem*) malloc(sizeof(ReallyBigItem));
item->x = 0;
item->y = 1;

array[0] = *item;
```

`ReallyBigItem* array = (ReallyBigItem*) malloc(sizeof(ReallyBigItem) * 8);`

I am allocating space for an array that fits in 8 `ReallyBigItem` structs.

`ReallyBigItem* item = (ReallyBigItem*) malloc(sizeof(ReallyBigItem));`

I am allocating space for a `ReallyBigItem` and storing it's memory address in `item`.

`array[0] = *item;`

Now I am setting the first element of the array to that item.

My question is:

Is the `=` operator actually **copying** over the already allocated memory? So the item struct exists in memory **twice**?

Comment: Yes, just as `int a = b` the value of `b` will then exist in memory twice.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the item struct exists in memory twice?

The content of the `struct` that `item` points to exists twice after the assignment in question, yes.

Explanation:

Both operands of this expression

```
array[0] = *item;
```

evaluate to a `struct`.

The `=` is defined for `struts`.

So the above expression copies data (memory's content, not "*memory*" as you word) from the right `struct` to the left.

This might be more obvious if you take into account that `*item` actually is the same as `item[0]`, so the above expression is equivalent to:

```
array[0] = item[0];
```

Comment: Thank you, makes more sense now. I was more curious for this for arrays of structs (`Item*`) instead of pointers to struct(`Item**`) which indeed seem to waste memory when setting the whole struct via `=`

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs: Please note that your code does not define any arrays, but just two pointers `array` and `item`, with one getting allocate to memory for eight `struct` and the other memory for one `struct`. They both are of the same type: `ReallyBigItem*` that is a pointer to `ReallyBigItem`.

Comment: `ReallyBigItem** ppa;` would define `ppa` to be a pointer to a pointer to `ReallyBigItem`.

Comment: `ReallyBigItem[42] a;` would define an array `a` of 42 elements of type `ReallyBigItem`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are copying the entire `struct` here. You could create a `ReallyBigItem **array` and just assign `item` (not `*item`) to just copy the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. You copy the whole struct.

Here's proof: http://ideone.com/cXZqNP

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} ReallyBigItem;

int main(void) {
    ReallyBigItem* array = (ReallyBigItem*) malloc(sizeof(ReallyBigItem) * 8);

    ReallyBigItem* item = (ReallyBigItem*) malloc(sizeof(ReallyBigItem));
    item->x = 0;
    item->y = 1;

    array[0] = *item;
    printf("%d - %d\n", array[0].y, item->y);
}
```